# In Java, is it more efficient to load all textures all at once or different times when needed

Tags: java, memory-management

Will it be more efficient to load all textures I need before in a loading screen, the game loads or separately when needed.

Comment: What does “efficient” mean here?

Comment: Loading everything into memory will consume more memory, but will prevent game stutter or graphics deterioration accessing the textures, assuming you have enough memory. Do you have enough memory? If yes, then loading all will slow startup but improve game experience. If no, then don't do it, since swapping will ruin game experience.

Comment: All my textures take up about 500Mb and i delete textures between game states that are not important and instead use smaller tiling textures

Comment: also by effiecient i mean that if i load textures sepratly that is becouse this will run as a applet and the textures will come from external source